Multiple lines linguex interlinear glossing
I am using linguex for my glosses. But I would like to be able to have two first lines, two glossing lines and two translation lines. But I do not know to do that. Here is what I would like to achieve :
Here is my minimal code, which actually triggers errors.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
 \exg. 
  wo daa pan  njanhan \\
 wo daa pan njanhan\\
  1PL   FUT come today\\
 1PL   FUT venir aujourd'hui\\
\glt    Nous will come today\\
\glt   Nous viendrons aujourd'hui\\
\end{document}

Thanks for your help.
